# Distinct condition to filter duplicate rows simultaneously with where clause

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I understand that distinct clause works after all the rows that match the specified condition has been fetched.

I am working on a Postgres database and I am joining two tables. My join where clause has close to 5000 conditions and takes a lot of time to execute for each row. It also is a *like* condition and hence takes a lot of time to execute. Here's an example.

```
+----+----------+
| id | column_a |
+----+----------+
| 1  | A,B,C    |
+----+----------+
| 1  | B,C,D    |
+----+----------+
| 1  | C,D,E    |
+----+----------+

select distinct id from a where column_a like '%A%' or column_a like '%B%'...(5000 other or conditions).
```

I want the database to not consider rows 2 and 3 once row 1 has already met the filter condition since it is going to get filtered out in the end anyway. Is there a way to do this in sql or pl-sql?

//EDIT

Adding Join Condition.

This is table B.

```
+----+-----------+
| id | column_a  |
+----+-----------+
| A  | some text |
+----+-----------+
| B  | some text |
+----+-----------+
| C  | some text |
+----+-----------+
```

So the join query looks like

```
select distinct id from a, b where a.column_a like concat('%',b.id,'%')
```

I am considering both the queries to be equivalent. In this first query, I am supplying the rows of the second table as multiple or conditions. In the second query, the join condition takes care of it. The problem remains in both the queries still.

Comment: Your query has no `join`, so I don't fully understand it.

Comment: You could consider using Window Function like RANK for example and add condition WHERE RANK = 1 at the end of your query.

Comment: Show us the join, when you are joining there is a possiblity to get rid of distinct with `exists` clause. Also I would suggest optimizing your conditions, and worry about distinct later.

Comment: If your data was json or an array, it could be done much prettier and much faster imo
Also, how on earth do you have multiple ID fields coming back from that query unless ID isn't the primary key... IMO, you probably need an aggregate function of some kind.

Comment: Join is the most important here, show us the join.

Comment: *"My join where clause has close to 5000 conditions and takes a lot of time to execute. It also is a like condition and hence takes a lot of time to execute."* - It is a terrible table structure then. I would suggest changing it.

Comment: @GergelyBacso I know right. I can't though as I can't even imagine the amount of code that would be impacted because of this change.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You can ignore that part as well. I just want SQL to not consider rows 2 and 3 when row 1 matches a certain condition because I am just selecting the id column and I want that to be distinct.

Comment: You want to influence the query engine so it doesn't consider rows 2 and 3? How can it know it doesn't have to consider them, before considering them?

Comment: I want the engine to check the records that have already matched the conditions first before beginning to execute the where clause with 5000 conditions.

Comment: Normal execution would be like row 1 matches condition so select id from row 1 which is 1. Row 2 matches condition so select id from row 2 which is 1. Now we have 2 1's. Distinct clause fires and filters the duplicates. I want it to execute as, row 1 matches condition so select id from row 1 which is 1. Row 2 has same id as row 1 and I am only selecting distinct id, so I dont need to check this row as it is going to get filtered out anyway in the end.